# Why PyQt5 import failed in Python3.4 with `ImportError: DLL load failed` in Windows 7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4, importerror, pyqt5

I have **32-bit** Python2.7 already installed in Windows 7 (64-bit Operating System) and I can use it without any errors. Besides, I attempted to install **64-bit** Python3.4 and PyQt5 in the same Windows 7.

I followed the steps given in this link: [Verify PyQt5 Packages Installed](http://projects.skylogic.ca/blog/how-to-install-pyqt5-and-build-your-first-gui-in-python-3-4/). I have installed **64-bit** versions of Python3.4 and PyQt5. As mentioned in the given link, in order to verify the installation when I typed: `from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets` I got this error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Is it possible that 32-bit Python2.7 causes this error message?

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you importing those modules from Python 2 interpreter? Because I have same installation for Python 3, PyQt5 (both 64-bit) and my Python 3 64-bit interpreter doesn't raise any error.

Comment: Actually true! I was importing those modules from Python2.7 interpreter. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too complex situation. You have 64-bit Windows, which can install both 64 and 32-bit software. So you can install both 2.x and 3.x in both variants. For each Python installation, there could be 4 type of PyQt available, 4 & 5, both in 32 and 64-bit version. So the possibility of error is `2 * 4 * 4 * 2` = 64 times complex. Jokes apart.

Let's look at the error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Let's break it down:

- `ImportError:` Nature of error we are getting is Import related. Python is not able to load specified module(s). Let's move forward.
- `DLL load failed:` This message more or less says that module was in form of `.dll` file.
- `%1 is not a valid Win32 application.` This error has most of the info. **`%1`**, which is more like an argument representing PyQt5, *is not a valid Win32 application.*

By looking at the error, it can be seen that interpreter looking for a Win32 application, which simply means a 32-bit application. But why would interpreter want a 32-bit module? Guess? Because interpreter itself is 32-bit!

It can't yet be said that it is Python3 or Python2 interpreter because error only specifies 32 or 64-bit information. But in your case it's your Python 2 interpreter because it's only the 32-bit interpreter on your system.