# How to install PyQt5 for Python 3.4 version?

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyqt5

I searched on the web and couldn't find anything. How can I install PyQt5 for Python 3.4 version?

Comment: http://robertbasic.com/blog/install-pyqt5-in-python-3-virtual-environment/ (for linux)  https://gist.github.com/guillaumevincent/10983814 (OsX)

Comment: @Prateek I'm on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For windows the executable (both 32 bit and 64 bit) should be available on the website https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.4.1/

Comment: There is a problem when I import PyQt5 only it's ok, but when I try to `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets` it says `ImportError: DLL load failed:`

Comment: Ohh okay. What problem?

Comment: I wrote it check please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692066/why-pyqt5-import-failed-in-python3-4-with-importerror-dll-load-failed-in-wind

Comment: Essentially check if you want a 32 bit or a 64 bit version of PyQt based on your environment

Comment: I wanted 32 because it seems like more 'problemless' but I couldnt find 32 for py 3.4

Comment: All the versions you want are on the website https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.4.1/

Comment: Problem solved thank you for the help! Also please add 32 version link to your answer so future visiters could see

Answer (score 0):

I am using pyCharm and it allows me to install PyQt5 from the settings menu, just go to the "Project Interpreter" and install it.

Comment: I'm not using any other interpreter. Normal shell only.

Comment: I'm also using Pycharm and Python 3.4. Using the Project Interpreter does not work for me and leads to: Collecting PyQt5.  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for PyQt5.