# how to convert qtdesigner to python file?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

i tried to convert an .ui file to .py
by this code in cmd :

```
pyuic5 test.ui -o test.py
```

but there was an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

how can i fix that?

Comment: We can't help if we don't have the ```test.ui```. Please include the file.

Comment: This was previously discussed https://stackoverflow.com/a/33868351/7548672

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why PyQt5 import failed in Python3.4 with \`ImportError: DLL load failed\` in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692066/why-pyqt5-import-failed-in-python3-4-with-importerror-dll-load-failed-in-wind)

Comment: @Nodejs-nerd  same link, click on mine above.

Comment: yes the problem is with importing PyQt5, thanks